# vuejs - sending post data to php

Tags: php, vuejs2, vue-resource

I am using `due-resource` to send data to `php`:

```
var data = {name: "abc", rank: "MID RANGE"};

this.$http.post('../../static/php/savedata.php',
      {postdata: JSON.stringify(data)})
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      });
```

Then process it and send back the data with `savedata.php` just to test:

```
<?php
$postData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
$rank = $postedData['rank'];

$arr = array('Status'=>'ok','rank'=>$rank);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

I get `null` for `rank`.
I tried other ways in `php`:

```
$postData = json_decode($POST['postdate'],true);
```

or

```
$postData = $POST['postdate'];
```

all of them give me `null`. What am I missing here?

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `JSON.stringify()` as the data should be converted for you automatically.  `this.$http.post('../../static/php/savedata.php', {postdata: data}...`

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what is wrong.

because my `data` is already an object, so i just need to:

```
this.$http.post('../../static/php/savedata.php',JSON.stringify(data))
```

instead of:

```
this.$http.post('../../static/php/savedata.php',{postdata: JSON.stringify(data)})
```